# Prevent Hyperlink on ASP text box validation

Tags: javascript, validation, asp-classic, hyperlink, spam

I am trying to stop spammers submitting Hyperlinks on a text box for a form.

The form asks the user to input their Full Name, Email Address, Telephone Number and then there is a box for them to enter a message. The Email Address and Telephone Number prevent hyperlinks because the validation specifies that the Phone can only consist of numbers, and the Email must contain an `@`.

Is there a way using Javascript combined with ASP that I can stop a form being submitted if it contains `(http)` or `(www)`.

I tried the following without success

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Validate(x, y) {
        str = (document.getElementById('Messagetxt')).value;
        if (str.match(/(http)(www)([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i) == null) {

            y.IsValid = true;
        }
        else {

            y.IsValid = false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Which is linked to a Custom Validator for the text box. When ever I enter `http`, `www`, or html tags `< >`, which I am trying to prevent, the form submits but presents an error page.

Comment: why not start using captcha?

Comment: and answer -- yes, it possible, even with your code. in <FORM> add onsubmit=return Validate

in javascript change Y.ISVALUD=true to return(true) and Y.ISVALID=FALSE to return(false)

Comment: Use Captcha. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/asp

Comment: If you don't have a CAPTCHA then JavaScript validation is probably not going to help too much. Without a CAPTCHA you need to be using server side validation. Also you mention a Custom Validator - is this Classic ASP or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Usually what you're experiencing aren't hackers but bots passing over your site.  I would recommend a more simplistic approach (maybe as well as) of tricking the bots into filling a hidden field.

Put a textbox on your form with a style set to `display: none;`, along with a completely unrelated id, something like `catchUnreal`. Check the value of `catchUnreal` on your server side code to see if it has a value.  If it does, it is highly likely that a bot has completed your form - don't submit the answer:

```html
<input type="text" id="catchUnreal" class="dontDisplay" />
...
...
```

```vb
<%if Request.Form("catchUnreal")<>"" then
    'Do my stuff
end if%>
```

(If you catch my drift).

**-- EDIT --**

Apologies - I wasn't reading properly.

The process above can also be applied using JavaScript by simply checking the hidden box value using JavaScript:

```javascript
if(document.getElementById("catchUnreal").value<>"") doProcessing();
```

**--Edit --**

Another idea is to use the server-side command `server.HTMLEncode(string)` which will remove any unwanted tag encodings.